# When building an electron + react app, I fire requests, are these made over http or https?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, http, https, electron

I have an electron + reactjs app, but when building it, I see that the process is run locally outside of a conventional URL, that is, how does react send information? In raw text (http) or in encrypted text (https), if it is http how can I encrypt and simulate this behavior even if electron is started at no url when built.

I intend to be able to encrypt the data sent (as on common https url sites) even if electron is started in a file inside the person's computer.